# Crear nuevos datos sin sobreescribir en Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, firestore

Estoy desarrollando una app de control de fichaje para un trabajo de la universidad, el problema es que cada vez que intento introducir los datos en la base de datos firestore me los sobreescribe, que debería añadir al código para que si la fecha es diferente añada nuevos datos?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("users").document(dato).set(/*tu hashmap*/, SetOptions.merge())
```

Solo agrega SetOptions.merge() como segundo parametro en el .set(). Esto hará que se fusionen los datos y sobreescriba solo los nuevos datos. Los iguales se quedan asi.

Comment: ¡Recuerda explicar siempre qué hace el código!